# How to auto publish user certificate to GAL (Exchange 2016)?

Tags: active-directory, exchange, certificate

I have set up a PKI infrastructure for my users, all is working fine : the CA, auto-enrollment, certificates published in AD and roaming mode enabled : everyone can log on any PC, automatically retrieve his certificate and use it to sign his emails.

BUT, there is one problem: the certificates, although published in AD (published certificates tab) are not automatically added to the GAL. One still need to go to Outlook -> Publish to GAL in order to receive encrypted emails.

There is little information on the internet, and when it's mentioned, everybody is assuming :published in AD = auto GAL publishing. But that's not the case, at least in my environment. Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure this is t an offline global address list issue? Outlook only syncs the GAL once every 24 hours.

Comment: The certificates never get auto-published in the GAL, no matter the time I wait for. But manual publishing in the GAL (via outlook) works fine.

Comment: How about run "Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited | Update-Recipient"?
Then, update address list, GAL and OAB.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved without any action, not sure what happened...

Comment: The change in AD not update to Exchange timely, like change user photo in AD, it will take some times to update it to Exchange. By the way, "Update-Recipient" will update and keep them consistent.

Comment: Exchange just sometimes does that. Not your fault. Sometime, restarting is really your only one option.

Comment: (I've been an Exchange administrator for several years. I know Exchange inside out. Sometimes, it just doesn't want to work and a full reboot is the only way out. And yes, I know it's awful. But sometimes it's the only way.)